# how to create combinations that do not repeat and store in a database in android studio?

Tags: android, mysql, combinations

I have spent days searching for an answer but no luck. I have a database with a table that has information I need to access to generate the combinations that are not repeated, with this I want to store the combinations into the column in the same table as a string array. Then I also want to display it as a toast when a button is pressed in another java file. Thank you for any help given, I am fairly new to coding so please make it easy for me to understand.

Here's my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_TABLE_NAME (
    CAR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    CAR_NAME INTEGER,
    CARTYRE_SIZE STRING,
    CAR_COMBINATION STRING
);
```

I want the data from `CARTYRE_SIZE` (e.g. `190LS`, `90L`, `78LA`) column to form the combinations which are non-repeating and order matters then put them in `CAR_COMBINATION` column. I would like these to be separated by ",".

so the output would be like:

```
190LS,90L
78LA,90L
190LS,78LA
190LS,90L,78LA
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do it randomly. Execute `UPDATE` several times if you need several combinations.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp AS(SELECT CARTYRE_SIZE FROM CAR_TABLE_NAME);

UPDATE CAR_TABLE_NAME p1
SET CAR_COMBINATION = CASE
    WHEN CAR_COMBINATION IS NULL
    THEN(SELECT CARTYRE_SIZE FROM tmp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
    ELSE CONCAT(CAR_COMBINATION, ',', (SELECT CARTYRE_SIZE FROM tmp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1))
END;
```

Comment: thanks for reply but could you show to implement in android studio.